# Differential Equation - Water evaporation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Given that a glass of water is filled to its fullest, $10\,cm$ in height, and that after **three days** the water level is at $9\,cm$ in height. Find when the glass will be empty.

The water is evaporating with a speed proportional to the surface area.

---

#### Own attempt, and where I'm stuck

$$\frac{dV}{dt}=-kS, \quad k > 0$$

$$dV = -kS\cdot dt$$

$$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad V = -kS\cdot t \quad\qquad\textit{From integrating}$$

Now, if the $S$, surface area, is constant, then I could easily calculate the change from $t=0$, and $t=5$ where $t$ is days after the initial scenario.

Here's where I am stuck. I have a suspicion, I would love to have it confirmed, and that is that the surface area does not matter; i.e. in some way, having a cylindrical glass with volume $V_\alpha$ and next to it a square glass with volume $V_\alpha$ means they will both be empty at $t = \beta$.

Otherwise, do you think I am to assume a shape, such as cylindrical or square by own choosing? *(First class of calculus, if this helps in answering the question)*

Comment: Sure, we don't really need calculus. The surface area is constant, so the rate of evaporation is constant, we are dry $30$ days after the experiment starts.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Oh yeah, that's right. I'm so used to thinking with *calculus* I forget to just think about the *basics*. However, I **now** assume the area is supposed to vary in the glass; albeit we know nothing about the shape, so then the last paragraph in my body texts remains.

Comment: If you really want to use calculus, let $y$ be height of water at time $t$. Then since $V=yS$ we have $\frac{dy}{dt}=-k$. Thus $y=y_0-kt$. You can use given info to find $k$.

Comment: If the glass is funny shaped, say wineglass, we cannot solve the problem from the given information. We do have to assume surface area is constant (cylinder, box).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we take "evaporating with a speed proportional to the surface area"
to mean that the rate of decrease in volume is proportional to the area
of the upper surface of the water, then the shape of the glass can be
cylindrical, spherical, conical, or just about any reasonable "cup" shape.

Consider the rate of evaporation, $\dfrac{dV}{dt}.$
We have $\dfrac{dV}{dt} = kA,$
where $A$ is the area of the upper surface of the water (not necessarily a constant)
and $k$ is a constant.

Now consider how we might compute the volume of the glass up to height $h$
using the "disk" method: in effect, we assert that as depth of water rises
(or falls) inside the glass, $\dfrac{dV}{dh} = A.$

From these two equations we can derive a value of $\dfrac{dh}{dt}.$
(One method is, use the Chain Rule to write 
$\dfrac{dV}{dh}\dfrac{dh}{dt} = \dfrac{dV}{dt},$
then solve for $\dfrac{dh}{dt}$ in that equation.)
The resulting value of $\dfrac{dh}{dt}$ is constant, 
even if $A$ is a non-constant function of $h.$

Comment: So, this means the *height* of the water will be in **constant** change while the change of the *volume* will **vary** (IFF the area is not constant). Did I get this right?

Comment: @B.Lee Yes, that is my interpretation of the problem. (Though I would say the rate of change in volume _may_ vary--it could be a cylindrical glass after all.)

Comment: A hint for computation of $dh/dt$ is now in the answer. It will (I hope) not be the last time you'll be deriving a rate from two other related rates.